# Is it possible to activate an alert on a created by field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, alert

I have a list where regular people are alerted via standard alerts while the inputter of an item is notified of modifications with a SPD workflow.

Is it possible to activate in some way the Alert Me standard function when a user inputs an entry?

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer: **No**,

In `Alert Me`, you must know who will receive the alerts beforehand. by defining his username or e-mail address at `Send Alerts To` field.

So The easiest workaround as you did is adding an action `Send Email` in your workflow to send an email as an alert to `User who created the current item`.